# No bash_profile and when I define it, it doesn't load

Tags: bash

Elementary didn't come with a ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile. I created the latter. I can manually enter `source ~/.bash_profile`, and it works. But when I start terminal cleanly, it doesn't automatically source this.

I'm going to go ahead and work around this by just modifying my ~/.bashrc, but that seems like a hack.

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.bash_profile` and `.profile` are only executed by login shells and text consoles. Terminal apps on GNU/Linux are neither so they use `.bashrc` instead.  AFAIK only macOS uses a login shell on its Terminal app, hence its use of `.bash_profile`.

Sourcing `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` to avoid maintenance of two separate files is pretty common so you don't need to worry about it being hack-ish.